# Bracket not showing as closed in Python 3

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error

I'm just starting to learn Python 3.9 as my first language. I have been fighting with this error for a while now, and I can't figure out what the issue is.

Here's what I'm working on:

```
def eval_express(eqstring[0], eqstring[1], eqstring[2]):
    eqstring[0], eqstring[2] = float(eqstring[0]), float(eqstring[2])
    return opdict[eqstring[1]](eqstring[0], eqstring[2])
```

I'm receiving an error that the "(" after `eval_express` is not closed, but as far as I can tell it is. At first, I thought it was just a glitch, but despite numerous attempts to rewrite it, increase/decrease the number of arguments, etc. it persisted. The error cropped up after I modified the arguments from variables to list items, but I don't see why that would affect it. Can anyone provide some clarification on what the program's getting hung up on?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using square brackets inside the function parameters, which is not valid. Valid code would be:

```py
def eval_express(eqstring0, eqstring1, eqstring2):
    eqstring0, eqstring2 = float(eqstring0), float(eqstring2)
    return opdict[eqstring1](eqstring0, eqstring2)
```

although you should probably use more descriptive parameter names.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `parameter[]` notation when entering a parameter to a function. Instead just use `parameter`, or you will have to do something like.

```
def eval_express(eqstring):
    eqstring[0], eqstring[2] = float(eqstring[0]), float(eqstring[2])
    return opdict[eqstring[1]](eqstring[0], eqstring[2])
```

Now you have to pass an array as the function parameter.

Comment: @juanguapo12 Keep learning